# How can I save my system?

Tags: dual-boot

I had Ubuntu installed, ( Dual Booted with Windows 10) and I wasn't using it anymore, so I deleted the partition for it. It was just free space. So I then decided to reset my PC through windows. (Wanted to do this for a while) When it restarted for the first time, it showed the following error and will not boot. I am at a loss of what to do here.

I haven't tried anything because I am unaware of any possible fixes, I did restart though.

I just want to get my computer back up and running with my Windows 10 installation.

```
Verifying DMI Pool Data .......
error: unknown filesystem 
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you deleted the Ubuntu partition you deleted the configuration files necessary for Grub to boot. But Grub is what is on your MBR and controlling your computer's boot process.

You need to restore your Windows bootloader. You can reinstall Grub when you reinstall Ubuntu,or by repairing windows with the windows installation media.

Using a windows media,boot to command prompt the type `bootrec /fixmbr` and your ready to go.

and using grub rescue

```
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,0)
grub rescue> make active
grub rescue> chainloader +1
grub rescue> boot
```

NOTE,your partition might be different with `(hd0, 0)` use `ls` to see what is yours and replace

Comment: How do I restore my Windows bootloader? I have a installation disc but don't know how to use it in this situation.

Comment: i have updated my and

Comment: It gives me an error "Unknown command '1s'."  When I type in 1s to grub rescue.

Comment: it is `ls` and not `1s`,,its L for lemon not one!

Comment: Okay so now it says:  (hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos4) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)                                                                 which one do I use?

Comment: It then says "filesystem is unknown"

Comment: It does that with every partition.

Comment: Same error, is there a way to boot a reinstallation DVD?

Comment: use the windows media and boot to the command prompt

Comment: how do you boot to command prompt?

Comment: start the media as if you want to install windows then enter on `Repair Your Computer` then `Troubleshoot` then Command Prompt`

Comment: Okay how can I get rid of Ubuntu completely so I can reset my computer correctly?

Comment: since you deleted the ubuntu partition,that means its no longer there anymore,all you have to do is fix the boot loader,type this command to the command prompt, `bootrec /fixboot` `bootrec /fixmbr` `bootrec /rebuildbcd` and voila!you are done.